# ssh tunneling not working due to strict iptables

Tags: ssh, debian, iptables, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

my iptables are set so that I can only allow ssh connections. I tried ssh tunneling and I can connect to my sever, but after when I try using my server as a proxy on firefox, pages try to load forever.

this is what the debug of the ssh tunneling displays. I know it's the output chain that is causing the issue because if I change the drop policy accept it works, but I'd rather open specific ports rather than have everything open. Is that possible?

```
debug1: Connection to port [tunnelport] forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 14: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port [tunnelport] forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 15: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port [tunnelport] forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 16: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port [tunnelport] forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 17: new [dynamic-tcpip]
```

these are my iptables

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports [sshport]
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:[sshport]
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
```

This is the command I use to set up ssh tunneling

ssh -v -TND [tunnelport] -i path to key -p [sshport] user@example.com

any help is appreciated. thx.

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it as an answer, not as an edit to your question.

Comment: Sorry. I posted an answer.

Comment: REAL iptables rules are needed. Post the output of `iptables-save -L`. And, what are you trying to do EXACTLY? Have you got a proxy software on the same server as your sshd server?

Comment: If I'm at school or somewhere else I simply would like to use an ssh tunnel to my home. It seems that I need to enable ports 80 and 443 in order to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I need to enable ports 80 & 443(http & https) on iptables to fix this. I can use http by itself, but sites like google and facebook will probably never load in a reasonable time.